# Logging akka configs on Application Start is not working in Play Framework 2.8

Tags: playframework, akka, threadpool, akka-http, application.conf

I am using latest play framework (2.8.12)
I am trying to Print akka configs on application start
Here is how my configs looks like

application.conf

```
play {
  server {
    # The server provider class name
    provider = "play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider"

    akka {
        loglevel = "INFO"
        log-config-on-start = on
        
        default-dispatcher {
               fork-join-executor {
                 parallelism-min = 8
                 parallelism-factor = 32.0
                 parallelism-max = 64
                 task-peeking-mode = "FIFO"
              }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to tune thread pool settings but none of changes seems to be effected. So trying to log configs on application start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would do is just print the provided config from one of your controllers for example.

```scala
@Singleton
class ConfigController @Inject()(val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents, val config: Config)
    extends BaseController {

  println(config.root().render())
...
}
```

Please note that will print full config including all `reference.conf` found in your classpath.

---

Regarding your `application.conf`, I think you misplaced the `default-dispatcher` config. It must be in `akka.actor` instead of `play.server.akka`

```json
play.server.provider = "play.core.server.AkkaHttpServerProvider"

akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"
  log-config-on-start = on
  actor.default-dispatcher {
    executor = fork-join-executor
    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 8
      parallelism-factor = 32.0
      parallelism-max = 64
      task-peeking-mode = "FIFO"
    }
  }
}
```

---

To make `log-config-on-start` work, make sure that you configure `logback.xml` logger `akka` to allow `INFO` logs.

```xml
<logger name="akka" level="INFO"/>
```

Comment: Wonderful. This worked perfectly. Also using akka.actor instead of play.server.akka fixed performance issue we had. Thanks @Ivan Stanislavciuc. Also can you please suggest, recommended values for parallelism params for a application which does frequent heavy DB operations ? If you can provide a doc, that also grateful.

Comment: That is worth a separate SO question. However, here are some directions for you to take. 1. Don't use default akka dispatcher for IO work (like DB access). More [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/dispatchers.html#solution-dedicated-dispatcher-for-blocking-operations) 2. Create a separate fixed pool dispatcher that has the number of threads matching the number of DB connections your application can have.

Comment: Thanks You Ivan. Is there any recommended values for production based on the machine specs ?